# What is this welding tool I found in my attic?

Tags: tools, welding

[image]
I believe this is used with welders because i found it inside a welding helmet.... Could somebody tell me what this is exactly?

Comment: Can you unfold the thing and show a clearer picture?

Comment: what happens when you squeeze the handle?

Answer (score 41):

[image: spark lighter]

According to an [ozzie web site](https://www.hampdon.com.au/spark-lighter-non-flint-electronic-electric-weldin), it's a non-flint electronic spark lighter.

Comment: how did you even find this from the pic ????

Comment: @mrid Google has a reverse-image look up feature.

Comment: also, text search on the Google takes "welding spark lighter" as a useful search term.

Answer (score 13):

It is a electric striker for lighting a oxy acetylene torch , I have the same one,
I bought it about 30 years ago.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.